# ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `my_path` with iomode `wi`

Tags: python, scikit-image, python-imageio

Code snippet giving the error:

```
for i in range(masks.shape[0]):
    imsave(os.path.join(PATH_TO_SAVE, f"prediction_{(i+1):04d}"), masks[i])
```

Error message:

```
"ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `my_path` with iomode `wi`"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the filename of the imsave argument, you have to mention the image type, for example, `bmp` or `tiff`

Corrected code snippet:

```
for i in range(masks.shape[0]):
    imsave(os.path.join(PATH_TO_SAVE, f"prediction_{(i+1):04d}.bmp"), masks[i])enter code here
```

Comment: ImageIO needs to know the format you want to save in, as there are many potential candidates. One way to provide this info is to give your output file a common extension (e.g. `some_file.bmp`). Another (in v3) is to pass `extension=".bmp"` kwarg.